# Value Error: Shapes (None, 21) and (None, 7, 7, 21) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Hello I am new to using keras. and I am doing an exercise with the VGG16 model.

I have loaded the model and now I have to Replace the last 3 fully connected layers with 3 new layers: the first 2 of 50 and 20 neurons respectively with ReLU activation, and a last layer with the appropriate number of neurons.

I have done the following:

`enter code here`

```
# Freeze the weights of the pretrained model layers
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

# Replace the last 3 fully connected layers with 3 new layers
x = base_model.output
x = Dense(50, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(20, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)

# Create a new model by joining the base of VGG16 with the new layers
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=x)
```

the model.summary() is like this:

=================================================================

input_13 (InputLayer)       [(None, 224, 224, 3)]     0

block1_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 224, 224, 64)      1792

block1_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 224, 224, 64)      36928

block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 112, 112, 64)      0

block2_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 112, 112, 128)     73856

block2_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 112, 112, 128)     147584

block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 56, 56, 128)       0

block3_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 56, 56, 256)       295168

block3_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080

block3_conv3 (Conv2D)       (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080

block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 28, 28, 256)       0

block4_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 28, 28, 512)       1180160

block4_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808

block4_conv3 (Conv2D)       (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808

block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 14, 14, 512)       0

block5_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808

block5_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808

block5_conv3 (Conv2D)       (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808

block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 7, 7, 512)         0

dense_6 (Dense)             (None, 7, 7, 50)          25650

dense_7 (Dense)             (None, 7, 7, 20)          1020

dense_8 (Dense)             (None, 7, 7, 21)          441

=================================================================

Total params: 14,741,799
Trainable params: 27,111
Non-trainable params: 14,714,688

---

When I try to train the model it gives me the following error:

*"ValueError: Shapes (None, 21) and (None, 7, 7, 21) are incompatible"*

What could be the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Flatten the output layer:

```py
x = base_model.output
x = Flatten(name="flatten")(x)
x = Dense(50, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(20, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)
```